# Is it a good idea to use Adobe Flash charts libraries on web applications?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, charts, libraries

I have been using jqplot for display charts on my web applications. But now my client wants more interactive charts, for drill-down navigation.

I think in use Adobe Flash charts libraries. But I have readed that flash have decreasing its presence on web apps and web pages in general.

So, Is it a good idea to use flash charts?
If I decided to use it, what things I have to keep in mind before?
What open source libraries there are that you have used before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, flash is not good idea. It completely unsupported on tablets (Apple, Android4+, etc).

Comment: I for one have Flash banned from my browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash charts are very attractive but they have costs. I've also worked in a project where i've used Flash charts. However, when those charts were no more rendering on iOS, my client wanted to replace them using HTML5 based charting.

So, if your target audience does not include iOS device users, you can go for Flash charting.

Also, the following link shows the trend of using flash is downward
http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/cp-flash/all/all

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it's decreasing it's presence, but it's also the support is decreasing, like for example on the mobile devices like iPad and iPhone. So if you want to be future proof I should use and combination of html5 and JavaScript.